# Google Sheets 'IF" to validate from a column not from a cell

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula

I'm trying to make the following condition work:

```
=IF(sheetcar!D8="B 770 AUT" ; IF(sheetcar!E8="yes" ; "yes" ; "no"))
```

But I want to make it search the whole column, something like

```
=IF(sheetcar!D="B 770 AUT" ; IF(sheetcar!E="yes" ; "yes" ; "no"))
```

This formula does not work. Is it possible to something like this with another formula?

Or do I have to use an extension or another program to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to refer full column like `sheetcar!D:D` and use array formula to make it working. Try below formual.

```
=ArrayFormula(IF(sheetcar!D:D="B 770 AUT",IF(sheetcar!E:E="yes","yes","no"),""))
```